# Eloquent, Retrieve results from nested relations query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Here is my query:

```
$profile = \App\ShippingProfile::findOrFail(2)
     ::with('costs')
     ->with( ['methods.zone' => function($query) {
      $query->where('id', 2);
   }])->get();
```

So I need shipping profile id 2, with related "costs" model and its related "method" with id 2, and the method's related "zone".

But I don't know how to get the result. If I try `->get()` , I get **all** ShippingProfiles, and if try

`->first()` I get profile id **1**.

So how would I retrieve the results? I have only seen "get", "first" and "find"...or is there something wrong with the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your current code. First of all you have a syntax error:

```
$profile = \App\ShippingProfile::findOrFail(2)
    ::with('costs')
```

The second `::` should be `->`.

Secondly, when you do `firstOrFail()` you're actually executing the query and returning a `Model` as a result. So when you're then chaining the rest onto the `Model` instance you're likely ending up with an error.

There are a couple of ways you can achieve your goal however. First of all, try using `whereKey` which adds a where clause to your query against the primary key, (just like using `findOrFail` does - but it doesn't immediately execute the query and return the model) and use `first()` to grab the model instance with the relations eager loaded:

```
$profile = \App\ShippingProfile::whereKey(2)
    ->with(['costs', 'method.zone' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', 2);
    }])
    ->first();
```

Alternatively, if you already have an instance of your model, you can use `load(...)`, in the same way as you would use `with(...)` to load your relations:

```
$profile = App\ShippingProfile::findOrFail(2);

$profile->load(['costs', 'method.zone' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('id', 2);
}]);
```